# Ionic2 dynamically set sidebar item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using latest version of ionic 2.

Ionic version: 2.1.8

I want to add item dynamically in a sidebar.

**app.component.ts;**

```
export class MyApp {

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, icon: any }>;

  this.pages = [
  { title: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, icon: 'ios-home-outline' },
  { title: 'Complaints', component: ComplaintPage, icon: 'ios-sad-outline' },
  { title: 'Suggestions', component: SuggestionPage, icon: 'md-bulb' },
  { title: 'Appreciations', component: AppreciationPage, icon: 'ios-thumbs-up-outline' },
  { title: 'Poll', component: PollPage, icon: 'ios-stats-outline' },
  { title: 'Survey', component: SurveyPage, icon: 'ios-analytics-outline' },
  { title: 'ReportIssue', component: ReportIssuePage, icon: 'ios-bug-outline' },
  ];

}
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
      <ion-icon item-left [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
      {{p.title}}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I want to show complaint item if complaint status is 'NEW'.

So, Is it possible to showing complaint item for some specific condition? I tried with **ngIf** but its do not work.

what is the best way to implement this kind of features?

Comment: Where you tried `*ngIf` and how?

Comment: Does that specific condition may change then in some other part of the code? So should the side menu be updated when that happens?

Answer (score 1):

have a variable in the component to check foe `new` complaints. If there are any, just set that variable to `true`.

```
export class MyApp {
   this.cmpltStatus;
   if(newCmplnt){
      this.cmpltStatus = true;
   } else{
      this.cmpltStatus = false;
   }
}
```

Now in ionic

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" *ngIf=(!cmpltStatus && p.title==='Complaints')>
      <ion-icon item-left [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
      {{p.title}}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: it will work only when user start app and at that time it has new complaint. but it will not work when new complaint is added when user is using the app. because app.component.ts is called when application starts. and its variable will not change dynamically once app is loaded. I'm looking for solution where we can add item from any other ts page any time.